# Refreshing Listview From Class with JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

I've been working on an app that's using a JSON parser to pull data from a database and display it in a ListView. It's based on code exampled [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). My problem is that when the main view is created, the ListView is populated by a class called `LoadAllProducts`, this works fine and re-checks from server and updates when I rotate the screen, but I want to add a button that will allow a manual refresh.

`LoadAllProducts` is called in `onCreate` simply as `new LoadAllProducts().execute();` but if I call that same line from a button `onClick` all it does is display the Loading dialog and doesn't actually do anything.

The full code is as follows.

```
package com.mystraldesign.aggregate;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.mystraldesign.aggregate.JSONParser;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> articlesList;

    // url to get all articles list
    private static String url_all_articles = "http://10.13.23.211/aggregate/api.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "articles";
    private static final String TAG_BODY = "body";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
    private static final String TAG_TIME = "postdate";
    private static final String TAG_SITE = "site";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Hashmap for ListView
        articlesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url)).getText()
                        .toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(pid));
                startActivity(i);
                // sending pid to next activity
                Intent in;


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_refresh:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                new LoadAllProducts().execute();
                // Loading products in Background Thread





                break;
            case R.id.action_copy:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void reloadArticles(View view)
    {
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }




    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Articles. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_articles, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Articles: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_BODY);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String uri = c.getString(TAG_URL);
                        Long timestamp = c.getLong(TAG_TIME);
                        String site = c.getString(TAG_SITE);

                        timestamp = timestamp * 1000;
                        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
                        String dateFormated;

                        SimpleDateFormat formatForDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d K:mm a");
                        StringBuilder convertedDate = new StringBuilder(formatForDate.format(date));
                        dateFormated = convertedDate.toString();

                        //Used to store Image ID for setting Image in ListView
                        int iID = 0;

                        //Find out the SITE name and set Image from Drawable Accordingly
                        if(site.equals("nyt"))
                        {
                            iID = R.drawable.nyt;
                        }
                        else if(site.equals("bbc"))
                        {
                            iID = R.drawable.bbc;
                        }
                        else if(site.equals("dm"))
                        {
                            iID = R.drawable.dm;
                        }
                        else if(site.equals("reuters"))
                        {
                            iID = R.drawable.reuters;
                        }

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_BODY, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, name);
                        map.put(TAG_URL, uri);
                        map.put(TAG_TIME, dateFormated);
                        map.put(TAG_SITE, iID);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        articlesList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */


                     ListAdapter adapter;
                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                           MainActivity.this, articlesList,
                           R.layout.list_row, new String[] { TAG_BODY, TAG_TITLE, TAG_URL, TAG_TIME, TAG_SITE},
                           new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.headline, R.id.url, R.id.time, R.id.list_i});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is reloadArticles your "onClick"?

Comment: I don't think u need the runOnUiThread because onPostExecute runs on the UI thread

Comment: @blackbelt No, cause I wrote that function to make it an easy call but I'm manually calling `new LoadAllProducts().execute();` in the onClick.

Comment: @chaitanya It does need it cause LoadAllProducts is called in a background thread for the JSON download and handling

Comment: post the original code

Comment: @blackbelt that is the originally code. The code I based it off didn't need a refresh feature as was structured in two views.

Comment: @JamesKraw As mentioned in the answer, onPostExecute is invoked on the UI thread, if u want a refresh, publishProgress might be a method to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way with proper memory processing.

Params:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> articlesList;
SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
LoadAllProducts mLoader;
```

Creating objects:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    // Hashmap for ListView
    articlesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    mLoader = new LoadAllProducts();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url)).getText()
                    .toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(pid));
            startActivity(i);
            // sending pid to next activity
            Intent in;


        }
    });

    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
           MainActivity.this, articlesList,
           R.layout.list_row, new String[] { TAG_BODY, TAG_TITLE, TAG_URL, TAG_TIME, TAG_SITE},
           new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.headline, R.id.url, R.id.time, R.id.list_i}); // empty list will be;
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    mLoader.execute();
```

Update button:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            mLoader.execute();
            break;
        case R.id.action_copy:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item 2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

No needs in "reloadArticles" method or just replace them's body with mLoader.execute();

Then remove data from existing list (to predict data duplicating):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mAdapter.clear();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Articles. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

And fill the adapter with new data:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                // updating listview
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1.onPostExecute it's UI thread

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
>   passed to this step as a parameter.

2.NotifyDatachanged call

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
//Here call notifydatasetchanged
```

3.Try **do not** recreate adapter, create it's once, and then just call clear() for clear items, and then add new. And also **notifydatasetchanged** it's

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.